# Access internal Neurons of a torch Neural Network

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch, luajit

What is a simple way to access the internal neurons of a neural network in torch?

I have trained a multi layer neural network using `nn` library of torch7. I want to see what are the output values from some particular internal neurons when some input is forwarded to the network, or change the outputs manually.

Are these possible? If so, are simple solutions for a network that is already trained and saved? The reason is that my neural network is an autoencoder, hence the neurons in the middle are important - kind of output of the whole network.

Answer (score 2):

if your neural network is called nnet and the layer of interest is middle_module, then do this:

```
middle_module = nn.Linear(...)
nnet = nn.Sequential(...)
nnet:forward(your_data)
local hidden_output = middle_module.output
```

The `output` instance variable of an nn module is always saved. This is due to the implementation details of backpropagation.

Edit: I realize you were asking about already-saved models. You can use `nn.Sequential.get` if you know the index of the module of interest.